# How to Subcribe to an update of database django

Tags: django

When using Django model, I have an table name "AppConfig".

What I want is that whenever there is an update on AppConfig table (inluding create,modify,delete) the result will log into a file.

Is there an convenient way to do it.

I can do this by adding log function to every point that I update the Config table in code. But it is quite messy and there is potential of mistake.

Comment: Are you aware of [*signals*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as said in the above comment you can make use of signals.

Give this a try,

Create a `signals.py` file in your app directory.

```
# signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete, pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import AppConfig

@receiver(post_save, sender=AppConfig)
def log_appconfig_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        action = "created"
    else:
        action = "modified"

    print(f"AppConfig {action}: {instance}")
    # Write Your Logic Here

@receiver([post_delete, pre_delete], sender=AppConfig)
def log_appconfig_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(f"AppConfig deleted: {instance}")
```

then register the signals in your `apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig # don't confuse with models.AppConfig

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'your_app_name'

    def ready(self):
        import your_app_name.signals
```

With this setup, every time an AppConfig instance is created, modified, or deleted, the corresponding message will be printed to terminal.